# cadastro com php e mysql nao salva

Tags: php, mysql

estou fazendo um cadastro simples no php e mysql só que ele não esta cadastrando e jogando no mysql eu fiz uma checagem caso desse erro ele retorna email repetido , e esta dando essa mensagem quando clico em salvar e nao joga no  mysql

```
include_once("conexao.php");

$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$cargo = $_POST['cargo'];
$data = $_POST['data'];
$endereco = $_POST['endereco'];
$cidade = $_POST['cidade'];
$estado = $_POST['estado'];
$cpf = $_POST['cpf'];
$rg = $_POST['rg'];
$ctps = $_POST['ctps'];


$sql = "insert into usuarios (nome,email,cargo,data,endereco,cidade,estado,,cpf,rg,ctps)
 values ('$nome' , '$email' , '$cargo', '$data', '$endereco', '$cidade', '$estado','$cpf', '$rg', '$ctps')";

$salvar = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql); //comando para salvar query

$linhas = mysqli_affected_rows($conexao);

mysqli_close($conexao);

?>
```

Comment: Além do mencionado na resposta do rapaz ali,o seu formulário está com os "names" certinhos nos campos ? O ideal era você só colocar o HTML do formulário. O resto é dispensável para a pergunta.

Comment: desculpa amigo estou começando no stack aqui vou pegar o jeito

Comment: Nada, cara. Não precisa pedir desculpas. Foi só um comentário que fiz. E fico feliz que a resposta do rapaz ali tenha lhe ajudado. Se você achou que a resposta foi útil, clique naquele "V", ali na resposta, para aceitá-la e para que o autor da resposta receba a pontuação.

Answer (score 1):

Pode ser uma (,) virgula que esta atrapalhando.
Seu exemplo:

```
$sql = "insert into usuarios (nome,email,cargo,data,endereco,cidade,estado,,cpf,rg,ctps)
```

values ('$nome' , '$email' , '$cargo', '$data', '$endereco', '$cidade', '$estado','$cpf', '$rg', '$ctps')";

Teste assim:

```
`$sql = "insert into usuarios (nome,email,cargo,data,endereco,cidade,estado,cpf,rg,ctps)
```

values ('$nome' , '$email' , '$cargo', '$data', '$endereco', '$cidade', '$estado','$cpf', '$rg', '$ctps')";`

Answer (score -1):

No comando $sql tem uma virgula a mais depois de estado!

$sql = "insert into usuarios (nome,email,cargo,data,endereco,cidade,estado,,cpf,rg,ctps) ...

Retira ela e veja se dá certo!

Comment: top irmao obrigado era isso obrigad mesmo sou novo por aqui to começando mas ja quero me tornar intermediario pelo menos desculpa a noobisse